# teradatasql Python module only works when scripting but not when running code

Tags: python, sql, teradata, dotenv

I have run into a peculiar issue while using the teradatasql package (installed from pypi). I use the following code (let's call it pytera.py) to query a database:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import pandas as pd
import teradatasql

# Load the database credentials from .env file
_ = load_dotenv()
db_host = os.getenv('db_host')
db_username = os.getenv('db_username')
db_password = os.getenv('db_password')


def run_query(query):
    """Run query string on teradata and return DataFrame."""
    if query.strip()[-1] != ';':
        query += ';'

    with teradatasql.connect(host=db_host, user=db_username,
                         password=db_password) as connect:
        df = pd.read_sql(query, connect)
    return df
```

When I import this function in the IPython/Python interpreter or in Jupyter Notebook, I can run queries just fine like so:

```
import pytera as pt

pt.run_query('select top 5 * from table_name;')
```

However, if I save the above code in a .py file and try to run it, I get an error message most of the time (not all the time). The error message is below.

```
E   teradatasql.OperationalError: [Version 16.20.0.49] [Session 0] [Teradata SQL Driver] Hostname lookup failed for None
E    at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).makeDriverError TeradataConnection.go:1046
E    at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*Lookup).getAddresses CopDiscovery.go:65
E    at gosqldriver/teradatasql.discoverCops CopDiscovery.go:137
E    at gosqldriver/teradatasql.newTeradataConnection TeradataConnection.go:133
E    at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataDriver).Open TeradataDriver.go:32
E    at database/sql.dsnConnector.Connect sql.go:600
E    at database/sql.(*DB).conn sql.go:1103
E    at database/sql.(*DB).Conn sql.go:1619
E    at main.goCreateConnection goside.go:229
E    at main._cgoexpwrap_e6e101e164fa_goCreateConnection _cgo_gotypes.go:214
E    at runtime.call64 asm_amd64.s:574
E    at runtime.cgocallbackg1 cgocall.go:316
E    at runtime.cgocallbackg cgocall.go:194
E    at runtime.cgocallback_gofunc asm_amd64.s:826
E    at runtime.goexit asm_amd64.s:2361
E   Caused by lookup None on <ip address redacted>: server misbehaving
```

I am using Python 3.7.3 and teradatasql 16.20.0.49 on Ubuntu (WSL) 18.04.

Perhaps not coincidentally, I run into a similar issue when trying a similar workflow on Windows (using the teradata package and the Teradata Python drivers installed). Works when I connect inside the interpreter or in Jupyter, but not in a script. In the Windows case, the error is:

```
E teradata.api.DatabaseError: (10380, '[08001] [Teradata][ODBC] (10380) Unable to establish connection with data source. Missing settings: {[DBCName]}')
```

I have a feeling that there's something basic that I'm missing, but I can't find a solution to this anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks [ravioli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58264097/2740563) for the fresh eyes. Turns out the issue was loading in the environment variables using dotenv. My module is in a Python package (separate folder), and my script and .env files are in the working directory.

dotenv successfully reads in the environment variables (.env in my working directory) when I run the code in my original post, line by line, in the interpreter or in Jupyter. However, when I run the same code in a script, it does not find in the .env file in my working directory. That will be a separate question I'll have to find the answer to.

```
import teradatasql
import pandas as pd


def run_query(query, db_host, db_username, db_password):
    """Run query string on teradata and return DataFrame."""
    if query.strip()[-1] != ';':
        query += ';'

    with teradatasql.connect(host=db_host, user=db_username,
                         password=db_password) as connect:
        df = pd.read_sql(query, connect)
    return df
```

The code below runs fine in a script now:

```
import pytera as pt
from dotenv import load_dotenv()

_ = load_dotenv()
db_host = os.getenv('db_host')
db_username = os.getenv('db_username')
db_password = os.getenv('db_password')

data = pt.run_query('select top 5 * from table_name;', db_host, db_username, db_password)
```

Comment: OK, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your client can't find the `Teradata` server, which is why you see that `DBCName` missing error.  This should be the "system name" of your Teradata server (i.e. `TDServProdA`).

A couple things to try:

1. If you are trying to connect directly with a hostname, try disabling COP discovery in your connection with this flag: `cop = false`.  [More info](https://pypi.org/project/teradatasql/#COPDiscovery)
2. Try updating your `hosts` file on your local system.  From the documentation:

> Modifying the hosts File
>
> If your site does not use DNS, you must define the IP address and the
>   Teradata Database name to use in the system hosts file on the
>   computer.
>
> 1. Locate the hosts file on the computer. This file is typically located in the following folder: %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc
> 2. Open the file with a text editor, such as Notepad.
> 3. Add the following entry to the file:   xxx.xx.xxx.xxx sssCOP1   where xxx.xx.xxx.xxx is the IP address and   where sss is the Teradata
>      Database name.
> 4. Save the hosts file.

[Link 1](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/5Z2iFFSaZfr3ZIGLbxnIHg/0J1SO9KwkTwgAwdqlIwxcA)
[Link 2](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/5Z2iFFSaZfr3ZIGLbxnIHg/0J1SO9KwkTwgAwdqlIwxcA)